Moving from 3-tier architecture to clean architecture
Generally, for a simple project: how do you move from 3-tier architecture to clean architecture? What I'm trying to do here is to get a feedback on how would the developer which understands 3-tier architecture and which read about the clean architecture easily follow the latter. Demystification.
NOTE: the example can be used for C#/.NET solution, and I believe it can be applied to other solutions as well.


Set up projects the way the clean architecture requires:

rename your Data Access Layer to Domain Layer
rename your Business Layer to Application Layer
add Infrastructure Layer


Update references (reference path: Presentation -> Infrastructure -> Application -> Domain)

Move database context and whatever database-related actions you have to Infrastructure Layer, while leaving models and business rules
in Domain Layer

Implement repository in Infrastructure Layer and interface it in Application Layer

Consume repository in the service of Application Layer


While doing so, pay attention to update file names, references,
service registration, configuration, namespaces... Just build the
project after each change and act accordingly.

That's how I see it. Would you agree?
EDIT
The implementation one would get moving from three-tier system the way it was explained is depicted in the image. I have deliberately been avoiding terms like flow/data control, input/output ports, etc in my question, because I believe one can build an intuition without understanding these intricacies and learn them later while trying to understand the system. What I wanted to say is that CA can be easily mentally grasped using the simple system setup in the code. As you can see, inner layers (or call them "lower layers" in multi-tier architecture) don't know of any types in outer layers, which makes the dependency graph acyclic. Yes, I was missing a graph in my initial question - sorry for that.

EDIT 2
After a series of answers and comments (that was great!), I came up with the conclusion that what I did could be just a first step in the CA direction. For example, if the projects that produce build artefacts are named the same as the respective tiers/layers they are part of, adding another such project into the layer will lead to unnecessary refactoring because of the naming. Which means the next step would be to separate projects from layers the way @Ewan mentioned. There must be more steps, and my idea is to focus on each of them at the time in order to show the differences between these two approaches in a simple way.
EDIT 3
I believe this question did not prove valuable to anyone. There is a significant amount of misunderstanding on all sides. I had an idea to go from the ground up and to use one scope of knowledge (dev) to shift to the other (architecture/design). I am a lecturer, and I found that "scope-shift" method to work in other cases. I don't know why it wouldn't work here, and everything here points out that it's simply wrong, no arguments.
I guess I made a mistake; the question was probably for some other SE site (maybe https://academia.stackexchange.com)

I guess you have a misunderstanding of what 3-tier application means: it means a system with 3 *physically" separated layers (like web client, web application, database, all on diffferent servers). Such a 3-tier system,  when restructured to follow the "clean architecture" ideas will keep being a 3-tier system after that, "clean architecture" only refers to the "middle tier". Maybe you meant "how to move a classical 3-layered business application to clean architecture". If that's what you really meant, please edit your question accordingly.

@DocBrown I don't believe that 3-tier system is about physical separation of layers. In what "physical" way does it have to be? Separate VMs, processes, pods, containers, projects, services... it's an different question and I can't say there's an universal answer. We first have to take ilities into account to answer that. The way I see it, there's a logical separation, and the motivation is to separate concerns.

doc is the best kind of right here :)

@Ewan I believe you mean correct ; )

@OzrenTkalcecKrznaric I appreciate the graph. But the meaning of [Bookservice] spanning both Application and Domain eludes me. Remember, one of the promised features of CA is that you can rip off an outer layer and drop on another one without touching the inner layers. This none-of-these-are-uml-so-who-knows graph seems to not be respecting that. What exactly does it mean?

@OzrenTkalcecKrznaric: it is see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitier_architecture. "Physically" means the parts can be executed on physically different machines, if one wants to. When we talk about "clean architecture", we look at the structure of an application in the "middle tier". The UI and database parts of such an application are the components inside an application which actually talk to a database or talk to a web browser on the client. There is no point in answering the question as long as it confuses a 3 tier architecture with "classical 3-layer business architecture".

@OzrenTkalcecKrznaric it sounds like Doc is sitting on a good answer to your question but justifiably wants your terms to be clear first. Doc is fairly good at this. Try giving him what he wants and see what you get. I bet you'll like it. I know I want to see it.

@candied_orange Damn, I do this all the time. It is elusive. I was refering to the ability to move the implementation of the service inside the Domain (i.e. as a part of the core business workflow) or leave it as a part of the Application.

@OzrenTkalcecKrznaric remember, objects in the outer layers have every right to abstract away details of the objects in the inner layers that they interact with. I don't think there is any real need to span the layers. All it means is you have to come up with more names.

Well, I am actually not sure if I should really write an answer, but assuming this question is about how to move from a standard three-
layer application to an application following the clean architecture ideas, I would recommend to have a look into Mark Seemann's book "Dependency Injection in .Net". In the 2nd chapter of that book you find exactly what you are looking for - a scetch of a classical 3 layered application ("doing it wrong"), and then how to rebuild the same application with DI in mind (which leads to a "clean architecture". ...(1/2)

... (hint: Seemann's book may be found online somewhere, probably a copyright violation, so I recommend buying a copy if you think it's useful). Note in the part "Doing it right", Seeman writes in the beginning: "Because DI is a radical departure from the way Mary created her application, I’m not going to modify it. Rather, I’m going to re-create it from scratch. You shouldn’t infer from this decision that it’s impossible to refactor an existing application towards DI; it can be done, but it’s hard.". (2/2)

@DocBrown How about getting it from the publishers website? Book is still worth the money.

@DocBrown That sounds great, thank you! And the funny thing is that I do have the ability to borrow that same book from the library. However, I need to say something that goes in somewhat opposite direction. As a developer, when I work with 3-tier architecture, I look at it as a complete form of the (sub-)system where I can focus my attention on any particular segment (call it module or tier, whatever) and analyze it with the ability to restructure part of it or even the whole thing if needed...  (1/2)

Implementation-wise it's usually a project/solution that can be easily run on my PC as a whole, with tiers as projects that depend on each other. And yes, you can call them layers. That's how I see it (that's even how Martin Fowler have seen it, right?) Also, the "Multitier Architecture" wiki page you mentioned doesn't require separating the tiers to be able to run them on separate machines, it's just stated as "most often". The last thing that confuses me is that I don't understand a difference between "3 tier architecture" and "classical 3-layer business architecture". Renamed concept? (2/2)

@OzrenTkalcecKrznaric sounds like you have the start of another good question. We like good questions. Just make sure we haven't answered it already.

@candied_orange you think I won't? :) Probably tomorrow, though, I have quite a bit to read now.

@OzrenTkalcecKrznaric: as I said, when speaking about a 3 tier system, we include the user's machine with its web browser and a typical HTML/Javascript frontend, a DBMS server (which is often running on a separate server), and a web application, running on a web application server. When we speak about a 3-layered system, we only look at the latter, the application, and how it is structured inside.

... or to make the difference more clear: a classical desktop application which connects directly to a database can still be 3-layered inside, but is still just a 2-tier application. Or it may be a 1-tier application, when it can only persist its's data into some local, embedded database or local files.

If you'll take advice from an old hand at this: don't debate in the comments. Seek clarity. My posts do their best when the only comment I post under them is "@commenter better now?"

... and no. it is is not necessary that the 3 tiers are installed on 3 different machines, but it should be possible, if one wants to. They could be 3 different micro services, for example. But definitely not "layers within one .Net / C# project which directly depend on each other by DLL references". So once we can agree on these terms, maybe you can consider to reword your question a little bit.

@DocBrown https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/455291/3-layer-3-tier-system

Would doing that let you do this?


crosp.net

The secret to doing that isn't using return. It's this:

Which is what happens when you fold up the Dependency Inversion Principle into a plugin.
Hopefully that shows you more is being called for here then just renaming and moving things. There is a discipline about what things are allowed to know about (depend on) that doesn't care about how information or control flows. CA insists that your object graph be acyclic. Generally, making sure inner layers don't know about outer layers accomplishes that.
Having flow of control go against dependency trips up many. But it's very powerful to be able to send control off somewhere else instead of back to the caller. That open arrow requires some form of polymorphism so you're not forced to know exactly where you're sending control.


cleancoder.com - The Clean Architecture

Add these considerations to your list and I think you're well on your way.

Actually, the code you would get by following the "recipe" maps to what you explained. Yes, it's just the small part of the system, but its pieces clearly follow the philosophy. Is there something I am missing here?

As long as there is some misunderstanding on my behalf, I believe that this is the most helpful answer here :)

TL;DR Stop, retreat, regroup and tackle this from a more productive angle.
The key advice here is that you should not learn an architecture from the perspective of how it's different from another architecture.
You should learn to build the new architecture from the ground up, so you understand its structure. Then, and only then, will you inherently be able to infer what changes you'd need to make to an existing codebase in order to migrate it to the new architecture.
The proof is in the pudding:


Set up projects the way the clean architecture requires:

rename your Data Access Layer to Domain Layer
rename your Business Layer to Application Layer
add Infrastructure Layer




This proves that you have not even understood Clean Architecture on its own, let alone being able to compare it to other architectures.
I'm not telling you specifically what's wrong here because the entire point is that you should be able to understand all of it. It would be counterproductive to iteratively point out your mistakes until you finally stumble onto the correct answer. Learn it from the ground up and understand it in isolation, before you start applying it to the real world and existing codebases.

I have deliberately been avoiding terms like flow/data control, input/output ports, etc in my question, because I believe one can build an intuition without understanding these intricacies and learn them later while trying to understand the system.

It is correct that you don't need to dig into every nut and bolt when dealing with high level architecture design. But dismissing the key concepts that go into that high level design in and of itself is setting yourself up for failure.
Do you need all of these things? Probably not. But intentionally not even bothering to consider them (nor understand them) is a bad idea for someone who (as this question proves) is trying to write a universal architecture migration guide.

What I wanted to say is that CA can be easily mentally grasped using the simple system setup in the code. As you can see, inner layers (or call them "lower layers" in multi-tier architecture) don't know of any types in outer layers, which makes the dependency graph acyclic.

Without any offense intended, your entire post is a textbook example of succumbing to the Dunning-Kruger effect. You are a student proclaiming to know what's universally correct, because you don't see any contradiction. The issue here is that you're not aware just how much there is that you're not aware of, which undermines the validity of your claims.

Without any offense intended? Really? You have just referenced my very first question on this Stack Exchange site as a simple example of something a cognitively limited person would ask? What happened with "there is no stupid question"? Sorry, I have to flag this. And one more thing - this is most upvoted? This is a textbook example of something else - a context becoming toxic.

@OzrenTkalcecKrznaric Flater has rejected your approach and presented a different one. Personally, I can see cases where both approaches could work. Your approach interests me not because I think it will always succeed when perfected, but because there would be a lot to learn when it fails. What you're proposing is nothing less than architectural refactoring. Might even be a book there. But...

I know for certain the Dunning-Kruger is in effect here because even though I've studied CA for years and show up in at least 45 of our posts about CA. Thing is, we have 246 posts about CA. Even with all my studying I'm still learning. I suspect Flater's point is less about about any personal deficiency and more a reflection of how ambitious your proposal is. It's not a small thing.

@candied_orange My comment was not about what he did, but how he did it. And other people just approved it flat out. I'm a university lecturer. I insist on certain standards of conduct with my students. I expect that here as well. Otherwise, I am really interested in why this is an incorrect approach, and as much as I need more explanation, your answer was the one conveying actual knowledge.

@candied_orange It is not necessary to justify his comment. One can't hit another with a stick and then let the others explain that it wasn't what he really meant. People should learn to show some respect.

@OzrenTkalcecKrznaric Well, you'd have to ask Flater how he meant it. All I'll say is this site is harsh. I took a fair number of lumps from sticks coming up through the ranks. Many from this guy named gnat. I don't think I'd have come this far without him. But then, gnat was always respectful.

@candied_orange Harsh it was from my first post here. Mind you, I do have a different opinion on things because things always depend on other things. So I weigh pros and cons. But if the expert group suppresses and silences a different viewpoint, where does it lead them? A probable outcome would be an echo chamber. Should we be going in that direction?

@OzrenTkalcecKrznaric to a little thing called politics. Which, this being an election year, I’ve had more than enough of. You’re right to expect respect. I won’t condone personal attacks. But harsh isn’t a bug here. It’s a feature. Because I’m trusting the people here with something important to me. What I should think.

@OzrenTkalcecKrznaric: CandiedOrange is correct that I was not calling you "a cognitively limited person". If you read the linked page, you will also see that the Dunning-Kruger effect makes no judgment on a person's abilities. It expresses a bias for any person to forget to account for the things that they don't know. This isn't a judgment on the specific person, it is a logical inevitability.

@OzrenTkalcecKrznaric: Secondly, I am in no way shaming or otherwise disincentivizing learning. But I am pushing back on your assertion of truths when you are still in a learning stage. As a university lecturer, I would hope you agree that it would be unproductive for you to "teach" by having your students make uninformed claims and have you tell them if they're correct/incorrect, and it would make more sense for your students to first study the course material before starting to apply that knowledge, because then they can apply that knowledge in an informed manner. [..]

[..] When your assertions contain inaccurate understandings of Clean Architecture on its own, that indicates that you need to improve your understanding of Clean Architecture, before you start making broad-sweeping statements about how different architectures relate to one another and how to migrate a codebase from one to the other. You cannot accurately compare things when you don't fully understand the things themselves. Your question reveals that you need to revisit your understanding of Clean Architecture, and I suggest you do so learning it from the ground up, in isolation.

@OzrenTkalcecKrznaric You can think it's harsh. I'm not going to argue what your feelings on this should be. But I am going to assert that at no point did I personally attack you personally or questioned your mental capacity (as you seem to have taken it, based on your comment). I criticized your proposal and claims, because they have faults. I pushed back on your approach of trying to state truths as a way of learning. I did so because it is an ineffective approach to learning, which will require an excessive amount of trial and error, and lies (early) on the road to dogmatic programming.

@Flater If we remove the assumption that your comment was offensive (which you may now explain in whichever way you like, but it won't change the fact), why do you believe that my insisting on inductive learning, from the code, cannot benefit one to start understanding the concept? That was my initiative. Demystification. Only later would I introduce the concepts. But initiative was simple — start with what students understand. Later explain new things they even don't understand they don't understand. Maybe that is so hard to accept because there are no lecturers here. I don't know.

@OzrenTkalcecKrznaric Cannot benefit? I never claimed that. I called it ineffective, not impossible. You're putting the cart before the horse, explaining something by telling people how it's different from something else. That does not do the core concept justice, nor does it create understanding of what it aims to achieve and how it does so. Sure, at some point you'll look at the practical differences between possible architecture implementations, but that doesn't mean it should be the foundation on which you build your theoretical understanding of the architecture in the first place.

@OzrenTkalcecKrznaric: Much like your original question, your latest comment seems built on the premise that if your intention is good, that therefore your approach must be good (and productive) as well. Subsequently, you take my criticism of your approach as if it were criticism about you or your intentions. Neither of these are correct interpretations. As good as your intentions are, you're going about it in an ineffective manner. But if you won't accept criticism on your approach, then it becomes impossible to address this issue and help you tackle this from a more productive angle.


Set up projects the way the clean architecture requires:

I think this is a common misconception based on various example solutions. You shouldn't have a project per layer. Projects are components and components go in layers.
I see lots of solutions where they have a project per layer and stuff them full of everything under the sun, which makes it an untestable mess. Web and Db are in the same layer, but don't put them in the same dll! If you have to show the layers in your solution, use solution folders.
Otherwise yeah, there isn't going to be huge changes assuming you have already separated your components and given them interfaces.
So I guess this needs elaboration.
Many blog posts about how to do CA in c# write a simple solution with the following structure
MySolution
 - InterfaceLayer (class lib project)
      Repository (class)
 - Domain (class lib project)
      MyModel (class)
 - Application (web project)
      MyController (class)

This demonstrates the layers are separate and allows you to show the dependency direction through project references, but the problem with this becomes clear when you add an extra component.
Let's say for example we are making a Blazor application, so the front end UI is also c# now you have:
MySolution
 - InterfaceLayer (class lib project)
      Repository (class)
      MyBlazorUIComponent (class)
 - Domain (class lib project)
      MyModel (class)
 - Application (web project)
      MyController (class)

Which obviously causes a problem. You don't want the data access implementation accessible in the front end. Or for them to reference each other at all.
Naming projects after layers is not "doing clean architecture" it's just a shortcut used to demo CA ideas. If you really want to show the layers in your code, instead of just you know, conceptualising them, use solution folders.
MySolution
 - InterfaceLayer (solution folder)
      Repository (project)
      MyBlazorUIComponent (project)
 - Domain (solution folder)
      MyModel(s) (project)
 - Application (solution folder)
      MyController (project)

Now if you get into an argument about what the layer is called or what layer a component should be in, it takes 2 seconds to move it and the code is not affected.

Er wait, what makes you say the OP is going for "a project per layer"? I don't see it.

under point 1 rename projects.. at least that's the way i read it, maybe ive just seen too many.

I read that as the layers getting renamed. I don't see a way to take it the way you did.

Yes, I wasn't clear about what "project" means here. I was referring to hierarchically organized units, which means that the solution also can be a project. However, for the implementation that can be confusing, so I just avoid it. However, for the simplicity I did map each of the projects to a particular layer. As long as it isn't general case, for simple projects (which I deliberately stressed out... you can call them simpler if you want) it does happen. Btw, whether layer and DB are in the same layer, it's an open question. But they surely are not in the same dll (pls read the question).

yeah, I think  even on a simple project layers==projects is a mistake. The example I give is that according to CA both the DB and the UI are in the same layer.

OK I stand corrected. Ewan has some valid concerns here. (I prefer to package by feature myself).

Can you explain it, like state a reason why layer==project is always a mistake? And while I agree that DB and the UI are in the same layer, it is not required per CA. As I understand CA, the number of layers and their names are not carved in stone but adaptable. Maybe I should have come up wtih the term like "sub-layer", meaning that persistence and UI are logically outside the adapting layer but are separate. I generally agree with you, but it always depends, you know.

@OzrenTkalcecKrznaric right, CA doesn't really speak to the packaging issue at all. Be careful trying to read more into it then is there. It's mostly on about managing what is allowed to know about what. It doesn't really care what bucket you drop stuff in. But there's more to design then just following CA. Ewan has a good point.

Although the number and names of layers aren't carved in stone, each layer has multiple "components". in c# the unit of component is the dll (as per uncle bob) adding "sub layers" mucks up the idea of references pointing inwards. Just have a project per component, Repository, WebBackEnd, WebFrontEnd, AccountManager, whatever and put them in solution folders called Domain, Application, Presentation etc if you want the layers to be named in your source code

@Ewan I understand what you are trying to explain. However, that was why I deliberately state "simple" in my question. I can be sketchy sometimes, I should have explained where does that simplicity come from - using simple case for a developer with knowledge about 3-tier architecture (or 3-layer if you will) to get a notion of Clear Architecture. According to what you propose, if we expand that simple system, the result would be then Domain (MyModel), Application (MyController, MyService), InterfaceLayer (MyRepository, MyBlazorComponents) That's a perfectly valid step in the direction of CA.

@OzrenTkalcecKrznaric it's not a valid setup, it would result in clients downloading versions of your repository because its in the same library as your UI component. That's if it even compiles

However, the reason i bring it up is because you mentioned the project renaming. Too many people seem to think that whatever they do, its CA if it has 4 projects with the layer names. You shouldn't need to rename any projects to convert from three layer to CA.
