3-layer / 3-tier system
Some years ago, I started using a particular architectural pattern that proved itself useful on a significant number of projects.
It includes the following concepts:

Presentation Layer/Tier that addresses presentation and user interaction
Business Layer/Tier that addresses business-logic
Data Access Layer/Tier that addresses persistence (e.g. database)

I've been referencing that architecture as a 3-tier architecture. For e.g. web technology stack it implies that there is something running in the browser, and there is also something that persists data. So, 3 tiers: browser-based tier addressing presentation concerns, database tier addressing persistence concerns, and business tier addressing business-logic concerns. But the application can be either constructed to run as a whole on my PC or on the server (example: MVC), or constructed to run components on different boxes (example: web API with React front-end).
Implementation-wise, these three types of concerns can be:

Bundled in the same project but somehow separated (folders, components, namespaces...)
Separated as different projects, but inside the same solution
Created to run as a completely different processes

In the first case, I call it a 3-layer system or application. Also a monolith.
In the second and third cases, I call it a 3-tier system or application.
Is my lingo correct? I am particularly interested in second case, application that is separated the way that is explained to different projects.
There is a great deal of literature that explains:

Layer is logical
Tier is physical

It seems that the type of application I am interested in has layers in terms of projects that are concerned about particular components (database, UI), and these components are tiers. So, it seems that this application can be considered both a 3-layer application and a 3-tier application. Is this correct?

See on Stackoverflow What's the difference between "Layers" and "Tiers"?

Moreover, when you speak of "projects" and "solutions", I guess you refer to Microsoft's Visual Studio / development terminology?

@DocBrown Yes, for the sake of simplicity, I'm talking about Microsoft VS. I think we can also talk about Eclipse workspaces with multiple projects depending on each other.

@OzrenTkalcecKrznaric there ony two tiers in your applications - client and server.

I gave you some explanations in my comments to your former question, as well as a reference to the Wikipedia article and now the Stackoverflow article above. Since all this material does not seem to satisfy you, I have no idea what I could tell you instead. Maybe someone else can give a better explanation than me.

@OzrenTkalcecKrznaric you seem to be focused on where these buckets are developed. I always focused on how they were deployed. Sometimes they're developed by people in different shops who never even talk to each other.

@Basilevs There are three of them: client, server and database

@DocBrown It appears that I am annoying by asking a very specific question that can be answered with yes or no. I can't help myself, I need an answer. Sorry for that.

@candied_orange The fact of the matter is: I am interested in both. Our former CA discussion was mostly about how the software is developed. Why would the discussion about 3-layer / 3-tier architecture be any different?

@OzrenTkalcecKrznaric is database truly developed by you? Or is it an external dependency?

@Basilevs I am not sure how is that relevant. Did you mean if the database development is a requirement of the system? If yes, the application layer is concerned with a deployed tier. If not, it's still an application layer concerned with a tier, but available as an external resource, not deployable with the system or part of it.

I still do not know precisely what to answer, but the number of of separate projects in a Visual Studio solution tells us nothing about the number of tiers of a system.

Think this has a stackoverflow answer :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/120438/whats-the-difference-between-layers-and-tiers

@DocBrown If that is the case, it's an important piece of the puzzle! The number of projects in Visual Studio being not important implies that there can also be a single project with multiple layers that concern multiple tiers deployed, and you can still call it a 3-tier system. Then the answer to my question would logically be a simple "no,"  right?

@Ewan A question about the difference between a layer and a tier is pretty much different than a question about how a particular system should be qualified as - 3-layer or 3-tier or maybe both.

@OzrenTkalcecKrznaric: it is not a huge problem to create a single self-contained Visual Studio web application project  in whatever programmer language you prefer, which can install its DB schema on a separate RDBMS (assuming certain access rights) which it expects, and which generates HTML which will be send to a separate web browser. Your VS project does neither contain the web browser nor the RDBMS., these  the upper and lower "tiers" for this case. It is also not a problem to create a single tier desktop application with 10 different VS projects, still no database and no browser involved.

@DocBrown phone screen small! apologies

The two concepts are indeed distinct yet somewhat correlated:

The layered architecture decomposes a system into layers of related software elements, where one layer communicates in principle only with the layer above or  below (or more generally, the neighbour layers).  This decomposition can be purely internal and invisible to the outside.

The tiered architecture decomposes a system into layers that are at the same time deployable components that can run as separate processes.


So layers are indeed somehow about the "logical" structure of the system whereas tiers is about the "physical" deployable items and run-time processes (I'd however advise to avoid the outdated and ambiguous term of "logical" vs "physical").
The two terms are correlated, in the sense that a tiered architecture is a special form of a layered architecture.  You wouldn't for example use the term "tiered architecture" for independently deployable microservices, since the deployable components do not correspond to horizontal layers (some argue it's a vertical slicing, but this is another debate).

I think this is largely a distinction without a difference. A 3 tiered application is always going to be 3 layered and a 3 layered application is always going to be 3 tiered.
Of course it's possible to make applications which break this rule, but no-one does.

"a 3 layered application is always going to be 3 tiered", em, no. You can have as many layers as you want inside an application and still stick to a single tier.

you can but generally you dont run a website on your db box

... and if you have some stand alone app, it would be odd to describe it as "a 3 layer app" even if technically it has three layers

Why should it be odd to describe an application which has 3 layers as a 3 layer app? For me it sounds pretty odd not to call it so.

people would think you meant three tier
